# Making a windows application for XP and Win7. Which Framework should I target?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-framework-version

I am trying to develop a windows application for a 3rd world country where most of the clients are Windows XP and a few a Windows 7 users. I would like to create an application where no further configuration is needed once installed.I am not sure where to start- I.e what .net framework to target and which OS to work in? Which one is more compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend .Net 4.0 that is the latest version supported by Windows XP.

`NOTE: All of the .Net framework run times are backward compatible. You also have to make sure that the application you develop is not targeted with a newer version of .Net than the computer with the oldest version of .Net`

*Here is some useful info*:

Windows Vista comes with 2.0 preinstalled.

Windows XP is being fazed out and does not come with .net out of the box, so I would target new computers. I understand if you company is NOT going to upgrade.

Windows 7 comes with 3.5.1 preinstalled. It is compatible up to 4.5.1 (as the time of this writing)

Windows XP comes with none preinstalled but is compatible up to 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make a **Windows** application is use c#...
If you want to export the application to other OS c/c++ are more compatible.

Comment: I am going to be using vb.net. Do you know what framework to target?i would like this to work in both xp and 7

Comment: @Oumie: Anything below .NET 4.5 should work, AFAIK. Are you aware that official Microsoft support for the XP platform is due stop within days?

Comment: Yes I know.. But this is for release in a country that doesn't utilize Microsoft support.. Thanks for the heads up by the way